# Upload a file using scp only if the file was updated/modified?

Tags: windows, ssh, synchronization, putty, scp

`pscp` is a very handful tool if you want to upload files to another server using SSH.

The only problem is that it is not able to detect if the destination file is already updated (based on datetime). I don't want to upload the file again if the file was not changed.

Is there any alternative for `pscp` that has this feature?

I would prefer a solution that is able to use `pageant` for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit of a heavy solution but cygwin+rsync would work if you set the environment correctly.

I believe but that [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) may work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for just for better `scp` client not `rsync`.

Comment: Unfortunately you will probably be looking for a long time.  I don't believe such a version of scp exists.

Comment: especially since rsync includes the ability to use ssh as a transport.

Comment: rsync isn't present on every Windows platform, like it is on Linux, but a range of ssh/scp clients do exist for Windows and it would be useful to find an answer on the question itself, i.e. how to achieve this using scp command only

Comment: @MladenB. I agree, but scp simply doesn't have that functionality.  On the plus side every modern version of Windows 10, can run WSL instead instead of using something like cygwin, or something else.  Getting an rsync client is pretty easy these days.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WinSCP...

It has an option to sync remote directories: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date

You can run it as a service if you'd like, to automatically watch your directory...

It's also scriptable: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate